# How do I style two empty divs (used for background images) sit precisely one above the other?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to line two empty `<div>`s one directly above the other, with basically the first `<div>` taking the top half of the screen and the second `<div>` taking the bottom half of the screen. Both `<div>`s contain background images, and need to line up perfectly (i.e. the bottom of the top `<div>` needs to be flush with the top of the bottom `<div>`) in order for the effect I'm trying to create to make sense.

What I have so far is this :

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.top {
  display: block;
  background-image: url(photo-top.jpg);
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  height:100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.bottom {
  display: block;
  background-image: url(photo-bottom.jpg);
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  height:100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This puts a huge white space between the top and bottom image. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following solution using `50vh` for each `<div>` as height:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.top {
  display: block;
  background-color:red;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1025/200/300);
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.bottom {
  display: block;
  background-color:blue;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1025/200/300);
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height:50vh;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

---

In case there is no other content below the two `<div>` elements you can use absolute positioned elements:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
.top {
  display: block;
  background-color:red;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1025/200/300);
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:50%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
.bottom {
  display: block;
  background-color:blue;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1025/200/300);
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height:50vh;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is definitely the right solution taking into consideration the browser compatibility (https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, this did exactly what I was looking for. Even led me to another mistake i'd made without realizing it. Thank you so much!